# animate width of li then return it back to default width

Tags: jquery

I'm wondering if it's possible to animate the width of an LI element on hover and then return it back to the default width onmouseout. I figured I could use .css() to grab and store the default value of the width in a variable but I'm not sure where or how to declare that variable so that it would work properly in the following code. Any help would be appreciated.  thanks

```
 $('#price-main-menu li').hover(function() {
$(this).animate({width:"250px"},400);
},
function() {$(this).animate({width: +a},400);
});
```

OK, I got a little further here and it looks like the key is $.data().  The following gives me an alert with the correct value in it but I don't think I'm referencing the variable correctly as the animate value.

```
 $('#price-main-menu li a').each(function() {
 $.data(this, 'width', $(this).css('width'));
 });

 $('#price-main-menu li a').hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({width:"250px"},400);
    },
    function() {
    var width = $.data(this, 'width');
    alert(width);
    $(this).animate({width: +width},400);
});
```

OK, answered my own question here (although stack overflow wont let me answer it).  thanks for looking though.

Got it.

```
 $('#price-main-menu li a').each(function() {
   $.data(this, 'width', $(this).css('width'));
 });

 $('#price-main-menu li a').hover(
   function() {
$(this).animate({width:"250px"},400);
   },
   function() {
var width = $.data(this, 'width');
   $(this).animate({width: width},400);
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the sample I made.(updated with the foreach you added, but I suggest to use `width()` instead of getting the css width)

http://jsfiddle.net/Quincy/5CALM/1/

```
 $('#price-main-menu li').each(function() {
      $.data(this, 'width', $(this).width());
   });
    $('#price-main-menu li').hover(function() {

      $(this).stop().animate({width:"250px"},400);
      },
      function() {$(this).stop().animate({width: $(this).data('width') + "px"},400);
    });
```

I used `data()` to store the original width and add the 'px' when setting the width.
Also I suggest you to add `stop()` to stop the current animation before doing current animation so it would look smoother.